# Logic for database design

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, database-design, database-schema

I am new to programming and I would like your input into a problem I am having. I am unable to visualize a certain part of a soccer statistics database I am creating.

I would like to associate a player with actions they perform on the field such as score a goal. Problem am having is I would also like to describe further the kind of goal scored and conditions surrounding the scoring of the goal. I would like to take care of these conditions for example:

1. The pattern of play (from open play, from a corner kick, from a free kick, from a throw in)
2. Skill employed (header, shot, chip, overhead kick, volley, half-volley)
3. Body part used (right foot, left foot, head, other)
4. Velocity of the ball (regular, weak, strong)
5. Extra information (Goalkeeper touch, via the post, deflected)

How do I associate one player with all these attributes which have their own sub attributes?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Soccer
(
ShirtNumber int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Skill varchar(255),
Velocity varchar(255),
ETC
);
```

I am new to this as well. But cant you crate a table which hold different attributes about what you need to know so you can query it later? Maybe Make Shirt number and/or First name a prim key. Or if you know for a fact there will never be the same number then make it jersey number.  You can edit the varchar from 255 to anything lower if you wanna limit the input. If you get better there is code on how to create drop down boxes to where you only select left/right foot or slow/fast Velocity. This is SQL code and to add drop boxs would be doing php code

Comment: Ryan, am looking at something more complex than that. Say in your example, skill has other parameters to it